# Use different eslint naming rules for class and interface properties

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I've been adding linting to a project using [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) and the [eslint-plugin](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin) and I need different linting rules for the properties of classes and interfaces. Currently I'm using the [naming-convention](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md) rule.

For class properties, strictCamelCase works great. But for interface properties, I need to allow both strictCamelCase and PascalCase.

I'd like to use strictCamelCase everywhere, but there are places in our code where I need to use DB columns as properties. For example:

```
class ActivitySearchModel extends common.Model {
    attributes: {
        ResultID: number;
        StartDateTime: moment.Moment;
        EndDateTime: moment.Moment;
        Label: string;
    };
}
```

This structure is pervasive throughout the codebase and cannot reasonably be changed. Aside from these attributes, everything else is strictCamelCase.

Is there a simple way to enforce different naming conventions for interface properties and class properties? Even better, would there be a way to only allow PascalCase on attributes? Is the only way to get this to work a custom rule?

The relevant parts of the eslintrc as it's currently set up:

```
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
        "error",
        {
            "selector": "default",
            "format": ["strictCamelCase"]
        },
        {
            "selector": "memberLike",
            "modifiers": ["private"],
            "format": ["strictCamelCase"],
            "leadingUnderscore": "require"
        },
        {
            "selector": "property",
            "format": ["strictCamelCase", "PascalCase"]
        },
        {
            "selector": "property",
            "modifiers": ["private"],
            "format": ["strictCamelCase", "PascalCase"],
            "leadingUnderscore": "require"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: try to change selector option as variable, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69244737/4751073