# Why does typescript-eslint enforce camelCase for enumMember?

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

All enum examples in the TypeScript documentation [write enum members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) as PascalCase, like:

```
enum Direction {
  Up = 1,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}
```

But [@typescript-eslint/naming-convention](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.16.1/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md) enforces camelCase (and rejects PascalCase), which means I have to write:

```
enum Direction {
  up = 1,
  down,
  left,
  right,
}
```

Is there a reason why PascalCase should be forbidden for enum members?

---

The context is a brand new Angular 12 project with the [recommended](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint) schematics:

```
ng add @angular-eslint/schematics
```

---

This makes no sense to me.

Is my set-up possibly wrong?

Why would the official naming convention be rejected?

Comment: There is no right and wrong, eslint does what they think is looking nice or is practical.

Comment: I can't be the first to be surprised that typescript-eslint would go against the TS documentation. I wonder if I made a mistake somewhere. I'm sure most developers follow the style of the official documentation...

Comment: I was also surprised with this rule for the same reason!

Comment: FYI I just overrode the rule in my .eslintrc.json:
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
          "error",
          {
            "selector": "enumMember",
            "format": ["PascalCase"]
          }
        ]

Comment: @franswa this helps but cancels all other checks for `pascalCase` - it's weird that the `eslint` rules contradict the documentation.. so annoying :(

Comment: @Itay Does it really? It should only for enum members.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know why, but to handle it, you can add this rule into the rules section of your 'eslintrc' config file:

```
"rules": {
    ...,
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
      "error",
      {
        "selector": "variable",
        "format": ["camelCase", "UPPER_CASE", "PascalCase"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Try to change "selector" and "format" options as you need:
[naming-convention available options](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.28.2/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md)

Comment: Doesn't this answer basically say, "here's how to write a rule for ESLint; figure it out yourself"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish feed him for a lifetime" In my view this is the corrected answer, it even links to the docs

Comment: This overwrites the default values for other selectors. The selector for this case should be `enumMember` instead. But you should add values for `parameter`. `variable` and other selectors. So, sadly, you should provide an entire set, like https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md#enforce-the-codebase-follows-eslints-camelcase-conventions.

Answer (score 3):

This was [reported as an issue against typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/6592), but sadly the maintainers refused to fix the (obviously wrong) default, citing historical reasons and concerns around breaking existing configs.

Therefore, for the time being, one is forced to fall back to a custom override. For example in the case of `.eslintrc.yml`:

```yaml
rules:
  "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention":
    - error
    - selector: enumMember
      format:
        - PascalCase
```

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the defaults if you have a `.cjs` config file, heres the entire file:

`.eslintrc.cjs`

```js
/* eslint-env node */
const typescriptEslint = require('@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin');


module.exports = {
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/strict-type-checked',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/stylistic'
    ],
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: true,
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    },
    root: true,
    rules: {
        // PascalCase enum members
        // bad default in https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/6592
        // means have to recreate the entire rule structure here by extracting the defaults from:
        // https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/naming-convention.ts
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
            "error",
            ...[...typescriptEslint.rules["naming-convention"].defaultOptions, {
                "selector": "enumMember",
                "format": ["PascalCase"]
            }]
        ],
    }
};
```